# CSS Gradient not working IE10+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a `box` that I'm trying to add some gradient to and it works in Chrome and other browsers except for IE10+  Below is my `CSS` code:

```
.box-gradient {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#CCCCCC),color-stop(50%,#EEEEEE), color-stop(50%,#EEEEEE), color-stop(100%,#CCCCCC));   
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try "background: `-ms-linear-gradient(...)`?

Comment: Upvote as `-ms-` works perfectly in IE 10+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include a line for IE10+

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(to left, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
```

I have had this issue before. Adding compatibility for gradients can be a very strenuous job. I think you'd prefer using **[gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need an un-prefixed linear gradient for IE10 to read. Something like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an unprefixed version as well:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#CCCCCC),color-stop(50%,#EEEEEE), color-stop(50%,#EEEEEE), color-stop(100%,#CCCCCC));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #CCCCCC 0%, #EEEEEE 50%, #EEEEEE 50%, #CCCCCC 100%);
```

There are plenty of [tools](http://css3please.com/) available to help you handle various prefixes.